# Lazy loading in Knockout JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, lazy-loading

I'm trying to load and parse json data from an external source into a table via Knockout JS. So far, everything has been successful through the following code:

```
    // Snippet
    var self = this;
    self.notices = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.currentTab = ko.observable(5);
    ko.computed(function() {
        $.getJSON('http://json.source.here.com/tab/'+ko.toJS(self.currentTab), function(threads) {
            if (threads !== null) {
                self.notices(threads);
            } else {
                self.notices([]);
            }
        });
    }, self.notices);
```

When a user clicks on a certain tab it would load the json data (forum threads) based on the selected tab value (self.currentTab) onto the table in the form of rows (self.notices).

Everything works as expected however, I noticed while browsing around other pages that do not have the above bindings, the json is still being loaded ($.getJSON is fired). I'm concerned that this may have some detrimental effects on the performance of my website as it is loading the json source even though it is not needed.

EDIT: I figured this out through Google Chrome's developer console.

I currently have my view model in a JavaScript file that is being used by every other pages as well. It consists of bindings for all the pages.

My question is, how can I load the json data on a specific page or only when the bindings are present - lazy loading? Preferably, I would like to keep all the bindings in a single JavaScript file, I do not want to separate them out and load them on a per page basis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is an article that I wrote on a simliar topic a little while back: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/lazy-loading-observable-in-knockoutjs.html

In your case, I think that you really want to add some guards around the `$.getJSON` call to ensure that it is only making AJAX requests when you are in the appropriate state (on the appropriate tab).

Along with that, the blog post describes using the `deferEvaluation` flag on a computed observable to ensure that the logic does not run until someone binds against the computed observable (in your case, you have an anonymous computed observable, but you could add it to your view model as a property and bind against it in your view.  Without this flag, the evaluation code will run when you create the computed observable, which is not desirable in your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I ended up using your Knockout JS plugin. However, I changed the "ko.observable" to "ko.observableArray" to serve my purpose better - that should be fine right? It seems to be working as expected now.

Comment: Yep, that should be no problem.  An observableArray is really an observable underneath with some extra methods added to handle array operations.

Comment: Thanks again. Oh and I just noticed that it does not seem to be updating when I click on a different tab. It should re-evaluate when one of the observable changes right?

Comment: If you can throw a basic demo in a fiddle, I would be happy to take a look.  If I understand what you are doing, then it is slightly different than the sample from the post.  You have one observableArray that holds your data and the contents are loaded when you change tabs?  If the function that loads your data takes the current tab into account, then you would just need to call `.refresh()` on the `onDemandObservable` when `currentTab` changes.  You can do this with a manual subscription: `self.currentTab.subscribe(function() { self.notices.refresh(); });` (if `notices` is on demand).

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WKTmW/ - I modified a few things but that's how it essentially works. It loads well the first time around but when the currentTab observable changes it does not trigger a re-evaluation.

Comment: Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/WKTmW/1/.  Basically, if you are going to use the onDemandObservable, then you need to call refresh() on it to retrigger.  This can easily be done using a manual subscription on `currentTab`.  Hope this helps.